# Почему коровы "бодаются"?

Tags: этимология

У коров есть рога, но они этими рогами почему-то *бодаются*. Как получилось, что слово "бодаться" не связано со словом "рога"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Бодать.** Искон. Производное от общеслав. бости < *bodti (dt > tt > ст), того же корня, что болг. бод «укол острым», «лезвие», диал. бодва «острога», лит. bèsti «колоть, втыкать, рыть» и т. д. Буквально — «колоть, тыкать».

---

Следовательно, слово *"бодать"* не особо связано с самим словом *"рога"*, а связано с действием, которое совершается этими самыми рогами. До слова *"рогаются"* наши предки, видимо, не догадались.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще не заметно, чтобы действия назывались по органам. Коровы не "ногают", а "ходят", не "ртают", а "едят" и "мычат", не "хвостают", а "машут хвостом". И другие животные тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Отчасти согласна с первым толкованием.БОДАТЬ=БОД+ять.,Корень БОД,БУД,родственнен корням :бот,бут,бит,бет-что в общем имеет одно древнее значение-визическое воздействие,удар,толчок,,но не укол или прокол...,именно тупой удар,тупым предметом-(бутом,ботагом,ботом,битой,бедром,ботаном)

Comment: Еще какие идеи будут? Метод "с потолка" очень продуктивный!

Answer (score 0):

От скотоводов иври  БАТ -пинок удар лягать брыкать.БД- давить ( отжим масла )
У нас также как предостережение быть Бдительным не допустить Б-Д- со стадом.

Answer (score 0):

```
  С искренним -
                                                                                                                                    Б. Александров
```

Comment: Да уж, это не с потолка! Это из под клюквы, развеситой.  
Открывать ссылку не буду, чур меня, чур ...

Answer (score 0):

> "кровать,постель,ложе"), происходят от инд-евр.корня "*bhedh"(прокалывать,рыть,копать). Значение"кровать,постель" получилось, вероятно,от вырытого в земле места для ночлега.

Не надо вот только предполагать! Давно известно, чтО там в постели прокалывают и кому. Даже Битлы используют жаргонное слово DIG в песне Dig a pony. По Вашему копают они что ли этого пони? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Как поясняет английский этимологический словарь (www.etymonline.com): английское"bed" так же,как немецкое"Bett"(оба означают "кровать,постель,ложе"), происходят от инд-евр.корня "*bhedh"(прокалывать,рыть,копать). Значение"кровать,постель" получилось, вероятно,от вырытого в земле места для ночлега. Кстати, в татарском языке имеется группа слов с корнем "бат"(углубление,погружаться на дно,тонуть)Например,"батма"(яма,выбоина,рытвина), "батынкы"(вогнутый), "бату"(утопать,погрузиться,быть вдавленным)

Comment: Ну, татарский-то язык точно не индоевропейский

Comment: Слова татарского языка приведены в связи с тем, что они являются свидетельством в пользу ностратической теории Старостина.

Comment: По поводу того, что "не заметно, чтобы действия назывались по органам. Коровы не "ногают"..." можно отметить такие глаголы, как лапать и глазеть.